# Cannot create a new image (x509 error)

Tags: lxd

Having a problem when I try to create a new `16.04 x64` Ubuntu container:

```
$ sudo lxc --version
2.0.3

$ sudo lxc launch images:ubuntu/xenial/amd64 my-container
error: Get https://images.linuxcontainers.org:8443/1.0/images/ubuntu/xenial/amd64: x509: certificate is valid for images.linuxcontainers.org, uk.images.linuxcontainers.org, us.images.linuxcontainers.org, not *.linuxcontainers.org
```

I'm running this from a `14.04 x64` Ubuntu machine. The error message seems a bit ambiguous as it specifies the host `images.linuxcontainers.org` in the list of valid servers and that is the same server the `Get` command it operating against (unless the port is important?)

How am I able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears when I change the image uri it works, for instance:

```
sudo lxc launch ubuntu:xenial/amd64 my-container
```

Yet, the documentation states I can use the `images:...` uri: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/#using-the-built-in-image-remotes

Answer (score 0):

it works with version 2.0.10

```
lxc launch images:ubuntu/xenial/amd64 my-container
```

[image]